# How to enable Mailbox audit log in Exchange hybrid Environment

Tags: exchange-server, office365, hybrid

Do I need to enable Mailbox Audit Log in On Premise or Office 365 in an Hybrid Environment.
Please give me  a advise

With regards,
Manidurai

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your mailboxes locates. If part of your mailboxes are in Office 365, and part of them are in on-premises, you need to enable audit log for them separately. Run Get-Mailbox command in both online and on-premises environment to get the corresponding mailboxes and enable them accordingly.
Since the audit log storage is part of a mailbox, after you enabled audit log for a mailbox, you can still move a mailbox to online or on-premises. Here's an article about considering audit log storage which might be helpful for you: http://exchangeserverpro.com/much-database-storage-mailbox-audit-logging-consume/